# external site does not load in iFrame for cordova

Tags: cordova

In the android app I built using phonegap/cordova CLI, I have an Iframe load external site. This works fine till now and suddenly stopped since last week.  In my config file I have

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
```

I put the meta tag in the index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

what changed in `cordova-plugin-whitelist` that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should also add the frame definition in your meta tag, like this:

```
frame-src * 'self'
```

Please consider that using wildcard is not safe.
Also you should add the following meta tag in your config.xml cordova file:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```